# How to divide a list into several single loops

Tags: pattern-matching, permutation

Because of some problems, I need to divide the permutation represented by a list into several single loop lists.

For example, for list `{4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5}`, it can be divided into two single loops `{4, 3, 2, 1}` and `{ 7, 6, 5}`, where  `{4, 3, 2, 1}` and `{ 7, 6, 5}` are continuous single loops (the single cycle in the positive direction and the single cycle in the opposite direction all meet the requirements).

```
PermutationCycles[{4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5}]
```

But the results of the above code do not meet the requirements, what should I do to achieve this requirement delicately?

**Other examples for testing:**

```
{3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5}
(*{{3,2,1},{7,6},{4,5}}*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[consecutiveRuns]

rule = a : {__} /; MatchQ[{1 ..} | {-1 ..}] @ Differences[a] :> a;

consecutiveRuns = SequenceSplit[#, rule] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
consecutiveRuns @ {4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5}
```

> ```
> {{4, 3, 2, 1}, {7, 6, 5}}
> ```

```
consecutiveRuns @ {3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5}
```

> ```
> {{3, 2, 1}, {7, 6}, {4, 5}}
> ```

For the example in flinty's answer:

```
consecutiveRuns @ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}, {0}, {2, 1}, {3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
updownruns[list_] := 
 Module[{s1 = Split[list, Abs[#1 - #2] == 1 &]}, 
  Reap[Do[If[SameQ @@ Differences[s], Sow[s], 
      Sow /@ TakeDrop[s, 1 + Length[First@Split@Differences@s]]
      ], {s, s1}]][[2, 1]]]
```

This handles cases like this:

```
updownruns[{3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5}]
(* result: {{3, 2, 1}, {7, 6}, {4, 5}} *)
```

But also cases like this:

```
updownruns[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}]
(* result {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3}, {0}, {2, 1}, {3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 2, 1}} *)
```

Comment: I am sure this could be simpler!